# SwiftUI Core Data ObjectWillChange with a computed var in Entity

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have an app that stores Person and MoneyEntries entities in a Core Data DB.

Person has 1:many relations to MoneyEntry. I created a computed var in an extension of Person that calculates the sum of all MoneyEntry entries related to this very person:

```
extension Person {
    var sumOfEntries: Double {
            var sum = 0.0
            entries.forEach({sum += $0.value})
            return sum
    }
}
```

In a first view I list all Person objects and the sum of their corresponding MoneyEntries:

```
struct PeopleListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var viewContext

    @FetchRequest var people: FetchedResults<Person>

    init() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastName_", ascending: true)]
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
        request.predicate = predicate
        _people = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: request)
    }

    var body: some View{
        ForEach(people, id: \.self) { person in
            Text("\(String(person.sumOfEntries) €")
        }
    }
}
```

In a second view I add a MoneyEntry object:

```
    let entryObj = MoneyEntry(context: viewContext)
    entryObj.person = person
    entryObj.value = valueAsDouble

    person.objectWillChange.send()
    
    try? viewContext.save()
```

But in my first view the sumOfEntries does not update. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Computed properties doesn’t subscribe to anything, have looked into core data derived attributes?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, In answer to your original question, Core Data Entities conform to `ObservableObject` so you could do this in your computed property:

```
extension Person {
    var sumOfEntries: Double {
            var sum = 0.0
            entries.forEach({sum += $0.value})
            objectWillChange.send() // Put it here
            return sum
    }
}
```

However, why would you? You could simply substitute

```
var body: some View{
    ForEach(people, id: \.self) { person in
        Text("\(person.reduce(0) {$0.entries.value, +}.description €")
    }
}
```

for:

```
var body: some View{
    ForEach(people, id: \.self) { person in
        Text("\(String(person.sumOfEntries) €")
    }
}
```

and compute it on the spot. It will always be current for the `Person` entity you are referencing without resorting to an `objectWillChange` publisher.

Comment: The alternative version you posted does not work that way. If you mean 
Text("\(person.entries.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.value}))")
this does not solve the problem. The entries Entity seams not to be updated.

Comment: Calling `objectWillChange.send()` into the sumOfEntries method does not solve the problem, too

Comment: You have got to post more of your code. I hacked together a quick working model of what you want, and it is updating fine. You really need to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I would especially be interested in seeing your `PersistenceController`, but you need to post a minimal example of what you are doing.